# Vuejs/Vuetify, data table server side on django rest framework, pagination isssue

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework, vuetifyjs3, vue-data-tables

i'm working a django api application that with such output :

```
{
    "count": 8025,
    "next": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/businessunits/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": []
    }
```

My get method back is quite simple using :

```
rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination
```

Been trying to implement the already paginated data into `v-data-table-server`
went that way to reduce latentaty cause of the bulk of the data i had to sent a paginated response.

js api call :

```
data() {
      return {
        loading: false,
        currentPage: 1,
        search: "",
        totalBusinessUnits: 0,
        options: {},
        sortBy: [],
        businessUnits: [],
        selectedColumn: null,
        headers: []....        

watch: {
          options: {
            handler(options) {
              this.getBusinessUnits();
            },
            deep:false
          },
        },
  

 getBusinessUnits() {
        this.loading = true;
        const { currentPage } = this.options;
        let pageNumber = currentPage - 1;
        const url = `${base_url}${bu_urls.get_all}?page=${this.currentPage}`;
        console.log(currentPage, pageNumber)
        axios
          .get(url, header)
          .then(response => {
            this.loading = false;
            this.businessUnits = response.data.results;
            this.totalBusinessUnits = response.data.count;
            console.log(this.options)
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error fetching business units:", error);
          });
      },




 created() {
      this.getBusinessUnits(); // Execute the getBusinessUnits method on component creation
    },
  
    mounted() {
      document.title = "Business Units";
      this.getBusinessUnits()
    },
```

on each call to the next page the options will change and move to the next page but the data being renderend is still the same data from the privious call.

Comment: Are you saying the watcher is not working? How is `options` changed? Please add all code necessary to understand the problem. Consider creating a [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/) with mock services where the problem can be observed

Comment: this is the whole code @MoritzRingler

Answer (score 0):

changing the `this.currentPage` to `this.options.page`
so  `let url = ${base_url}${bu_urls.get_all}?page=${this.options.page}&page_size=${itemsPerPage}`